# Route problems with OpenVPN through a local Astaro firewall

Tags: firewall, routing, openvpn

I am trying to connect to a OpenVPN server on my Windows 7 desktop though my Astaro (ASG) Firewall.  I got it setup and can connect just fine but I can't surf the web.  I can ping websites like google.com so DNS and some routing is working.  I am trying to figure out if the problem is a setting in my firewall.

This is what I allowed in the firewall:

```
Computer (10.10.1.71)  --> 1:65000 to 1194 (UDP/TCP) --> VPN DNS Group
```

So after I connect I look at the routing table and I'm just confused.  Can someone post a link to a good website that explains how the Windows 7 routing table is read.  Also can someone explain how mine is read?

Are there any reasons why Astaro might block the traffic?  Nothing shows in Live Firewall log and IPS is currently disabled.

```
//local ip      10.10.1.71   
//local network 10.10.1.0/24
//local Subnet  255.255.255.0

// vpn ip     10.109.84.6
// vpn subnet 255.255.255.252

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.10.1.1       10.10.1.71      5
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      10.109.84.5      10.109.84.6     30
        10.10.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.10.1.71    261
       10.10.1.71  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.1.71    261
      10.10.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.1.71    261
      10.109.84.1  255.255.255.255      10.109.84.5      10.109.84.6     30
      10.109.84.4  255.255.255.252         On-link       10.109.84.6    286
      10.109.84.6  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.109.84.6    286
      10.109.84.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.109.84.6    286
    50.23.113.234  255.255.255.255        10.10.1.1       10.10.1.71      5
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      10.109.84.5      10.109.84.6     30
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.1.71    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.109.84.6    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.1.71    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.109.84.6    286
===========================================================================
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to get the OpenVPN connection working when connecting using 443/tcp.  Which makes me believe that something in my Astaro ASG (firewall) is blocking the connection for some reason.  I'm still determined to figure out why 1194/udp is not working (for everything) even though I added the rule into my firewall to allow the traffic.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!